# LedgerFailure - Trying to sync to testnet

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I am getting an error when trying to sync to testnet with 1.29.0 and using the genesis files from https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/index.html

I have deleted my db several times and tried 1.29.1: Same error and same spot (I think).

error:

```
[ip-172-3:cardano.node.ChainDB:Error:34] [2021-09-19 09:06:40.67 UTC] Invalid block 7828c58252b1eb59487fc363d88771b6e08fa52841f39e54bf39b5322e45efd4 at slot 36812798: ExtValidationErrorLedger (HardForkLedgerErrorFromEra S (S (S (S (Z (WrapLedgerErr {unwrapLedgerErr = BBodyError (BlockTransitionError [ShelleyInAlonzoPredFail (LedgersFailure (LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (ValidationTagMismatch (IsValid True) (FailedUnexpectedly [PlutusFailure "\nThe 3 arg plutus script (PlutusScript ScriptHash \"9e7068208dae0dc0aea9e1b17e40ad3a606dead9bfbe4f1dadded7a6\") fails.\nCekError An error has occurred:  User error:\nThe provided Plutus code called 'error'.\nThe data is: List []\nThe redeemer is: List []\nThe context is:\nPurpose: Spending (TxOutRef {txOutRefId = 08629328abe7bf6d6da80d7e8e717be9546be831aee4ce0c13506afa82fb83c8, txOutRefIdx = 1})\nTxInfo:\n  TxId: 94ac30c3c1887333de9e278975e5a1a4f8179473634ce07e185f75137bb405f1\n  Inputs: [ 08629328abe7bf6d6da80d7e8e717be9546be831aee4ce0c13506afa82fb83c8!0 -> - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",973242561)])]) addressed to\n                                                                                    addressed to PubKeyCredential: ba0971f1837884f35ef6b4a4556034c5db0c1af7ddaa46412f718b18 (no staking credential)\n          , 08629328abe7bf6d6da80d7e8e717be9546be831aee4ce0c13506afa82fb83c8!1 -> - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",1930992)]),(4f99b1003eddbd87f229f4ca35723753eb9b941efda6c82f3fc10bfe,Map [(\"LobsterNFT\",1)]),(fda1b6b487bee2e7f64ecf24d24b1224342484c0195ee1b7b943db50,Map [(\"LobsterCounter\",43)])]) addressed to\n                                                                                    addressed to ScriptCredential: 9e7068208dae0dc0aea9e1b17e40ad3a606dead9bfbe4f1dadded7a6 (no staking credential) ]\n  Outputs: [ - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",972266644)])]) addressed to\n               addressed to PubKeyCredential: ba0971f1837884f35ef6b4a4556034c5db0c1af7ddaa46412f718b18 (no staking credential)\n           , - Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",2068920)]),(4f99b1003eddbd87f229f4ca35723753eb9b941efda6c82f3fc10bfe,Map [(\"LobsterNFT\",1)]),(fda1b6b487bee2e7f64ecf24d24b1224342484c0195ee1b7b943db50,Map [(\"LobsterCounter\",44),(\"LobsterFinished\",1)])]) addressed to\n               addressed to ScriptCredential: 9e7068208dae0dc0aea9e1b17e40ad3a606dead9bfbe4f1dadded7a6 (no staking credential) ]\n  Fee: Value (Map [(,Map [(\"\",837989)])])\n  Value minted: Value (Map [(fda1b6b487bee2e7f64ecf24d24b1224342484c0195ee1b7b943db50,Map [(\"LobsterCounter\",1),(\"LobsterFinished\",1)])])\n
```

The command I am running is:

cardano-node run 
--topology testnet-topology.json 
--database-path db 
--socket-path db/node.socket 
--host-addr 127.0.0.1 
--port 3001 
--config testnet-config.json

I built from src following directions here: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node

Only change was checking out 1.29.0 instead of 1.27.0

.. output of cardano-node --version:

```
cardano-node 1.29.1 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 8617cc395b9493d9b5fa05bebc8644a7384c103e
```

Comment: Please update with the process you had followed till you got this error.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted cardano-node back to 1.29.0 and issue resolved itself.